# If Else Formula for Date field in Crysal Reports that keeps Date format - not string

Tags: oracle, date, if-statement, crystal-reports

I have a formula in Crystal Reports to convert for a particular date. The formula is working, but converts the field to a string, and I need the field to be a date as I am exporting as a CSV file and then loading data to a table. 
Is there a way to use this same logic but have the field remain as a date
and not a string? Below is the current logic that I am using:

```
if  totext((Date(Year({Command.RENEWAL_DT}), Month({Command.RENEWAL_DT}), Day({Command.RENEWAL_DT}))),'dd/MM/yyyy') = "01/01/1800" then
   "01/31/2099" 
else 
   totext((Date(Year({Command.RENEWAL_DT}), Month({Command.RENEWAL_DT}), Day({Command.RENEWAL_DT}))),'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this

```
if  totext((Date(Year({Command.RENEWAL_DT}), Month({Command.RENEWAL_DT}), Day({Command.RENEWAL_DT}))),'dd/MM/yyyy') = "01/01/1800" then
   "DATE '2099-31-12'"
else 
   "DATE '" & totext((Date(Year({Command.RENEWAL_DT}), Month({Command.RENEWAL_DT}), Day({Command.RENEWAL_DT}))),'yyyy-MM-dd') & "'"
```

Or use the [TO_DATE()](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions219.htm#SQLRF06132) function.

Comment: That populates the field as "DATE'2099-12-31'" and as a string. Can you use TO_DATE in Crystal Reports formula's?